# How to give a download option

Tags: php

I am making a site on which I'll give users the option to download software.

I want to know what to do for that.

For example:

```
To download xyz software click here
```

and if the user clicks on it, the download starts.

Answer (score 4):

```
<p>You can download <a href="/url/to/the/file/to/download">the thing that you want</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```
function download($path, $filename) {

  header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename . '"');
  $fp=fopen($path . "/". $filename, 'r');
  fpassthru($fp);
  fclose($fp);

}
```

Next, you have to set values for $path & $filename & call the above function like this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_download_directory";
$filename = xyz_software.zip;

download($path, $filename);
```